# How to input monthly data for time series plot in R?

Tags: r, ggplot2, dplyr, zoo, ggfortify

I have data stored in .csv file which has two columns:

```
Date    mean
201001    234
201002    167
...
...
...
202005    289
```

(format is yyyymm)

I want to create a time series plot for the same. I am trying to do so using the following code in R:

```
library("zoo")
library("dplyr")
library("ggplot2")
library("ggfortify") 
alb_mean <- read.csv("D:/Monthtest/alb_mean.csv")
View(alb_mean)
ff <- zoo(alb_mean$mean, seq(from=as.Date("201001"), to=as.Date("202005", by=1)))
```

It gives me following error: Error in charToDate(x) :
character string is not in a standard unambiguous format

Why it is giving me this error? Do I need to change the date format? Kindly help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

csv means comma separated values but there are no commas in the data shown in the question so we will create an actual csv file in the Note at the end and use that. First read it into a zoo object using `read.csv.zoo` -- if the data is in the format shown in the question as opposed to csv then use `read.zoo(text = "lab_mean.csv", header = TRUE, FUN = to.ym)` instead.  In either case convert the first column to yearmon class which represents a year and month without a day. Then plot it using `autoplot`.  See `?autoplot.zoo` for further customizations.

```
library(ggplot2)
library(zoo)

to.ym <- function(x) as.yearmon(as.character(x), "%Y%m")
alb_mean <- read.csv.zoo("alb_mean.csv", FUN = to.ym)
autoplot(alb_mean)
```

[image: screenshot]

```
## Note

Lines <- "Date    mean
201001    234
201002    167
202005    289"
Lines |>
  read.table(text = _, header = TRUE) |>
  write.csv("alb_mean.csv", row.names = FALSE, quote = FALSE)
```

Comment: Thanks. The code is working. But there seems an issue in plot (may be it is due to date format). My axis shows dates as 201010, 201020, 201030....and so on.. Why is it considering Jan (01) as 10 and so on? Is there any way to convert 01, 02 in 201001, 201002 to Jan 2010, Feb 2010...? Kindly help

Comment: The code shown already does precisely that -- it takes a sv file whose first column is  of the form yyyymm and produces an axis as shown in the image. Start a fresh session in R and paste in the code in the Note to produce alb_mean.csv in the current directory and then examine the file so you can see that it has the format described in the answer.  Then run the code in the body of the answer and you should get exactly the output shown in the image in the answer.  Maybe you have something different than you described in which case we would have to know what it is.

Comment: On starting a fresh session, it worked successfully. Thank you very much.

Answer (score 0):

Your `Date` column is not a [`Date`](https://www.stat.berkeley.edu/%7Es133/dates.html) object. `as.Date("201001")` produces an error because R does not know what the format is. Your sequence should be:

```r
ff <- zoo(
    alb_mean$mean, 
    seq(from = as.Date("2010-01-01"), to = as.Date("2020-05-01"), by = "1 month")
)
```

However, this will only assign the correct values to each `mean` if your original data has no missing months and is in date order. It is safer to use the values from the `Date` column, appending `01` to put them in `"%Y%m%d"` format:

```r
ff  <- zoo(
    alb_mean$mean, 
    as.Date(paste0(alb_mean$Date, "01"), format = "%Y%m%d")    
)
```

Comment: Thanks. Is it essential to incorporate day in date format? Can't it be only month and year because my data is monthly average.  In plot, I want to keep it as Jan 2010, Feb 2010...

Comment: If you want to use an R Date object then you need the day. However you can format the date to only print the year and month in your plot, e.g. `format(as.Date("2023-04-15"), "%b %Y")` will print `"Apr 2023"`.